# Notice: Undefined variable: template but $template is defined?

Tags: php

I'm busy with my template engine, and when I try to load a param it gives this error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: template in C:\xampp\htdocs\global.php on line 21
>   Fatal error: Call to a member function makeCut() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\global.php on line 21

but in the engine itself:

```
<?php

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
include('app/includes/classes/class.db.php');

class template extends DB {
    public $template;
    public $content;
    public $variables = array();

    public function makeCut($name, $value) {
        $this->Cut['{' . $name . '}'] = $value;

    }

    public function getCut($content) {
        $content = str_replace(array_keys($this->param), array_values($this->param), $content);
        return $content;
    }

    public function echoPage() {
        echo $this->getCut($this->content);
    }
}

$template = new template;
```

(I did cut out a piece)

So what's going on here?

EDIT: Some lines of my global.php

```
    function __autoload($class_name) {
    require_once('app/includes/classes/class.' . $class_name . '.php');
}
require_once('app/includes/languages/lang.' . LANGUAGE . '.php');
// Params
$template->makeCut('slider', "<?php include('sliders/' . $users->slideCheck(); . '.html'); ?>");
?>
```

Comment: Stating the obvious: does your `global.php` include the "engine" file where `$template` is defined before using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, your `global.php` doesn't include the file which defines the `template` class, so `$template` is never instantiated before use. `__autoload` can automatically load files if a class is needed, but it won't know to load a file if a variable is needed.