# Notice: Undefined property: template::$param

Tags: php

So, again a problem with my parser.
These errors:

```
Notice: Undefined property: template::$param in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\includes\classes\class.template.php on line 35

Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\includes\classes\class.template.php on line 35

Notice: Undefined property: template::$param in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\includes\classes\class.template.php on line 35

Warning: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\includes\classes\class.template.php on line 35
```

The line that causes the errors:

```
$content = str_replace(array_keys($this->param), array_values($this->param), $content);
```

Any answers?

Comment: Based on the [code you provided in your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23440222/1233508), you seem to be using `$this->variables`, `$this->Cut` and `$this->param` interchangeably - you need to pick one of those and stick with it. Please don't make us hunt through your past questions to find context, link to them if they are related. Also, this is the kind of error that can be rather easily resolved if you look at the "Related" question list in the sidebar.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: @DCoder Call me stupid, but I don't see anything helpfull...

Answer (score 0):

are you returning an object to twig template instead of array.
getArrayResult if using doctrine.